# WPF Animation is Choppy

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, wpf-controls

I am trying to use some animations to make my application feel good. But I could not help the choppy animation that no matter what I do, it is always end up stuttering.

Take a look:

```
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation()
                 {
//ht is height of DockPanel, I wanted to start from 200 less than Actual DockPanel Height
                         From = ht - 200,
                         To = ht,
                         Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                         AccelerationRatio = 0.5,
                         DecelerationRatio = 0.5
                     };
    x.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, anim);
    //x is the UserControl
```

Also, what I need to animate is a custom **UserControl**, which contains some text like 100 words and bunch of **Images**. I just want to make it grow in to the height of the current **DockPanel** as soon it is loaded.

What I saw by searching for the solution is this,

```
Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(anim, 10);
```

Even trying any value in there nothing really happens.

Answer (score 0):

Framerate is like the frame rate of a film.

A low frame rate will give you a choppy film or a choppy animation.

Using a dockpanel is probably a bad idea for some content you are going to animate, because it will try and adjust things every time your height changes.

I suggest you go with a grid instead.

You should use a scaletransform.  Partly because as you animate height you will find all the content of your usercontrol have their measures invalidated and they will want to start off the whole measure arrange cycle many times.

If you're thinking measure arrange? Then read up on how the wpf layout system works.

I would also advise you to use xaml rather than code.

Here's some code to think about:

```
    private void StartAnimate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tran = testRectangle.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1d, 1d)
        {
            CenterX = 0.5d,
            CenterY = 0.5d
        };
        var anim = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            To = 1.0,
            From=0,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5d),
            DecelerationRatio = 0.5d,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
        };
        tran.BeginAnimation(
             ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty,
             anim,
             HandoffBehavior.Compose);
    }
```

I put a rectangle and my button in a dockpanel to prove this works.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Name="testRectangle"
               Width="500"
    />
    <Button Content="Animate"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Name="StartAnimate"
            Click="StartAnimate_Click"  />
</DockPanel>
```

A rectangle is pretty simple but it animates smoothly.

Comment: I appreciate that, but here are some problems : 1. I want my UserControl to fill the background and hence I used DockPanel since there was nothing that could work for me! I tried using Grid but to my surprise, no matter what I do it doesn't fill up the whole space. Plus there will be no resizing of window, so changing the height won`t be any of a problem.

Comment: I can say we both have the similar approach here, but you used a rectangle which is way too simpler than a user control with images and lot of text.

Comment: The big difference is I use a scaletransform. That will transform anything in whatever control you like. So it doesn't matter how complicated your usercontrol is. The layout will not change dynamically like with animating the height and it will not be anywhere near as choppy. Unless you still set framerate to 10.

Comment: Sorry but I tried using ScaleX and ScaleY both none seem to work either.